# C# WPF. Создать и использовать фрейм в dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

Как создать dll с фреймом внутри и загрузить этот фрейм в другом приложении?

Искал ответ на даный вопрос но нашел только примеры с формами.

Comment: может добавить в dll код инициализации фрейма, но я тоже не понимаю как сделать это

Comment: Что такое фрейм? Просто создайте UserControl Class Library проект (или как он там называется)

Comment: Если под фреймом имеется ввиду элемент Frame, то зачем его экспортировать? Он нужен для отображения содержимого в виде страниц Wpf. АндрейNOP правильно написал, смотрите в сторону UserControl, ну или страниц